# which Windows VPS to choose for cron jobs/scheduler

Tags: cron, windows-services, hosting, vps, cron-task

I have a web *crawler* which I want to execute every 5 min. As other members adviced here, I will need for that a VPS hosting and running cron jobs.

However, I am not too good with configuring things and not too friendly with Linux. Therefore, I have decided to go for a windows VPS. As I found on the net, windows has a "scheduler"  , which is equivalent on cron jobs on Linux.

My Q is:
What kind of Windows should my VPS have so that the configuration will be easy and not require too much admin-skills?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Task scheduler is a native part of Windows 2008 or Windows 2012 Operating system. When you navigate to Start Menu, Go to Administrative Tools and you will see Task Scheduler over there. So, you just need to buy a Windows VPS having Windows server 2008 or Windows Server 2012 Operating system. You just need basic VPS management skills to set task scheduler and other tasks. Here is a guide you can refer to schedule a task in Windows VPS:

https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2166/How-to-Schedule-a-Task-in-Windows-Server-2008-VPS.html